# Why does running IncrediBuild from the command line on my Qt app never halt?

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2013, incredibuild

I use Visual Studio 2013 with IncrediBuild to compile Qt apps.  Through the IDE everything works fine, but when running on the command line, `BuildConsole` never returns.

Process that are running:

- `BuildConsole.exe`
- `cmd.exe`
- `devenv.com`
- `devenv.exe`
- `MSBuild.exe`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out, the `qt5appwrapper` step was the piece that was never finishing.
I could see this by opening up IncrediBuild's Build Monitor window and seeing that that portion was just going and going and going...

**Uninstalling the `Qt Add-in 1.2.4` fixed the problem.**

This is done by running `Qt5VSAddin\uninst.exe`.  I found it in my start menu under `Qt5 Visual Studio Add-in` (not from inside Visual Studio).